# ajaxの非同期通信時にUnable to autoload constant ControllerとUncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . , compile errorのエラーが発生する

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, 非同期

初めての質問です！
ruby on railsで現在製作中の投稿型アプリケーションの投稿機能に、ajaxで非同期通信を適用させようとしています。

createアクションにrespond_toを使って、json形式でデータをとり、ajaxでデータを返すという具合です。

ところが、いざ実装してみると一つのエラーを抜け出せず、投稿がままならない状態です。
エラー内容は、

`Unable to autoload constant MessagesController, expected /Users/namae/projects/chat-space/app/controllers/messages_controller.rb to define it`

というエラーと、
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`
`compile error`
というエラーが複数出ています。

以下に非同期通信周りのコードを載せます。

`[messages_controller]`

```
def create
  @message = @group.messages.new(message_params)
  if @message.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to group_messages_path(@group)}
      format.json
  else
    @messages = @group.messages.includes(:user)
    flash.now[:alert] = "メッセージを入力してください"
    render :index
  end
end
```

`[message.js]`

```
$(function(){
  function buildHTML(data){
    var Image = '';

    if (massage.image) {
      Image = `<img src = ${message.image} class = "lower-message__image">`
    }

    var html = `<div class="message" data-message-id=${ message.id }>
                  <div class="upper-message">
                    <div class="upper-message__user-name">
                      ${ message.name }
                    </div>
                    <div class="upper-message__date">
                      ${ message.data }
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="lower-meesage">
                      <p class="lower-message__content">
                        ${ message.text }
                      </p>
                        $ { Image }
                  </div>
                </div>`;
    return html;
  }

  $("#new_message").on('submit', function(e){ //フォームを送信した時に
    console.log("this")
    e.preventDefault();                       //アクションを止めてページの遷移を止める
    var formData = new FormData(this);        //フォームの情報獲得
    var url = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    });
    .done(function(data) {
      var html = buildHTML(data);
      var url = $(this).attr("action");
      $('.message').append(html);
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('error');
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

`[create.json.jbuilder]`

```
json.id         @message.id
json.text       @message.body
json.image      @message.image.url
json.data       @message.created_at.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
json.name       @message.user.name
```

至らないところが多いですが、わかる方、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 念の為に確認しますが、messages_controller.rb には `class MessagesController < ApplicationController` などの様な定義があるのですよね？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！あります。

Comment: 綴り間違いの可能性はあります。`messages_controller.rb`という綴りのファイルはありますか?もしくは、`MessagesController`という綴りのクラスは定義されていますか?

Comment: ありがとうございます！
おかげさまで解決いたしました。
createアクションのrespond_toのendがないだけのエラーでした！ご協力ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

コントローラーのどこを探しても間違いはないと踏んでいましたが、

結局 message_controllerのcreateアクションのrespond_toのendが抜けていただけでした。

協力してくれた方、ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

まず、エラーメッセージを見てみましょう
"Unable to autoload constant MessagesController, expected /Users/namae/projects/chat-space/app/controllers/messages_controller.rb to define it"
(直訳：定数 MessagesController がオートロードできません。
/Users/namae/projects/chat-space/app/controllers/messages_controller.rb で定義されていると期待していたのですが。。）

という事なので、messages_controller.rb の内容を確認してください。
質問に書かれている messages_controller.rb の内容の出典はどこですか？
そのサイトに何か説明がありませんでしたか？

＝＝

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。
おっしゃる通り、message_controllerの記述を確認したのですが、イマイチ間違っていると思えなくて。。

ruby on railsの同期通信はうまくできていて、createアクションに改めて非同期を採用した際にエラーが出るようになったので、ajaxの記述にミスがあると睨んでの投稿です。

message_controllerの記述に関しては、出典は特にありません